# samba with OpenLDAP - NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER

Tags: samba, ldap

1. OpenLDAP (working with ldapsearch and php scripts)
2. Working samba without LDAP

This is what my `access.log` says (where all my smb data gets dumped):

```
[2013/02/10 19:41:25, 2] passdb/init_sam_from_ldap(545): Entry found for user: ***<username>***
[2013/02/10 19:41:25, 0] passdb/pdb_get_group_sid: Failed to find Unix account for ***<username>***
[2013/02/10 19:41:25, 1] auth/make_server_info_sam(589):  User ***<username>*** in passdb, but getpwnam() fails!
[2013/02/10 19:41:25, 0] auth/check_sam_security: make_server_info_sam() failed with 'NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER'
[2013/02/10 19:41:25, 2] auth/check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [***<username>***] -> [***<username>***] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
```

It's like the password hashes in the OpenLDAP database doesn't match what samba assumes it should recieved, or something along those lines.
**note:** When supplying a wrong password, it says wrong password.. these logs are for a perfect authentication using correct credentials, or at least i try to (via gnome filebrowser, username: **username**, workgroup: WORKGROUP, password: **plain text password**)

Here's my smb.conf:

```
[global]
        unix charset = LOCALE
        netbios name = test
        server string = test
        passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://<ip>"
        username map = "/etc/samba/smbusers"
        log level = 2
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/access.log
        max log size = 0
        name resolve order = hosts dns
        load printers = No
        add user script = /usr/bin/smbldap-useradd -m '%u'
        delete user script = /usr/bin/smbldap-userdel '%u'
        add group script = /usr/bin/smbldap-groupadd -p '%g'
        delete group script = /usr/bin/smbldap-groupdel '%g'
        add user to group script = /usr/bin/smbldap-groupmod -m '%g' '%u'
        delete user from group script = /usr/bin/smbldap-groupmod -x '%g' '%u'
        add machine script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd -t 0 -w "%u"
        set primary group script = /usr/bin/smbldap-usermod -g '%g' '%u'
        domain logons = Yes
        domain master = Yes
        wins support = Yes

        ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=test,dc=local
        ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
        ldap user suffix = ou=People
        ldap suffix = dc=test,dc=local
        ldap ssl = no
        ldap passwd sync = yes
```

Here's my ldap.conf

** Server is down so i don't have this atm**

According to wireshark OpenLDAP sends the correct information when searching for the `uid`, but when doing the actual login i **think** that samba says something about **"singelLevel"** which i think might be relevant, this is where it fails and the "wrong" data is sent back to samba.

Samba just refuses to use any LDAP login.

### shares:

They work without LDAP, so the share's fine! (even with non-ldap auth)

### **Add a unix user**

This works... Then i can access the share, but i've explicitly told samba to **not** use local authentication, i've chosen LDAP?

Comment: Again, i'm terribly sorry for any missleading information, type-o or if i'm unclear or missing anything.. I'm just about on the edge of panicing >_<

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where samba used LDAP for a backend, yet still required a local Unix account for the user in order to allow domain logons.

The problem for me was to do with the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file which lists the databases to query for user accounts and groups etc. You have not specified what Linux OS you are using, so I will give you the steps I used to resolve the issue on my Ubuntu box.

First I had to install the `libnss-ldap` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap
```

There were also several dependencies, one of which is `ldap-auth-config`. If the ACLs on your OpenLDAP server prevent anonymous searches then you will need to specify an ldap account e.g. `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com` that has access to the LDAP database, during the configuration of this package.

Following that, edit the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. Add 'ldap' to three entries for passwd, group and shadow as shown below. Some systems use 'compat' and others 'files', so you can just leave the first bit alone.

```
passwd: compat ldap
group: compat ldap
shadow: compat ldap
```

The change should take effect immediately. You can confirm that it worked by issuing the `getent` command:

```
getent passwd
```

It should list all local and LDAP user accounts.